# Does not work -hls_playlist in ffmpeg in the -dash section

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

I will use this assembly ffmpeg
https://hub.docker.com/r/jrottenberg/ffmpeg/

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 6.2.1 (Alpine 6.2.1) 20160822
```

I'm trying to do dash and hls at the same time.

In the documentation from here http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#dash-2

the key is:

```
-hls_playlist hls_playlist

Generate HLS playlist files as well. The master playlist is generated
with the filename master.m3u8. One media playlist file is generated for
each stream with filenames media_0.m3u8, media_1.m3u8, etc.
```

those. mpd and m3u8 must be created at the same time.

Running:

```
ffmpeg -re \
-analyzeduration 20000000 \
-i udp: //239.0.0.1: 1234? overrun_nonfatal = 1 \
-map 0 \
-c copy \
-f dash \
-min_seg_duration 5000000 \
-window_size 10 \
-extra_window_size 10 \
-remove_at_exit 1 \
-hls_playlist 1 \
-use_timeline 1 \
-use_template 1 \
-vtag avc1 \
-atag mp4a \
cam01.mpd
```

and get an error:

```
Unrecognized option 'hls_playlist'.  
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found`
```

without the `-hls_playlist`
everything works correctly ...

What could be the problem ?

Comment: The ffmpeg minor version is old. You'll need a recent git binary.

Comment: @Mulvya  thank you, in the new version it works.

Comment: @Mulvya There is another problem, it does not work as I expected.
The file master.m3u8 is empty and does not contain links to media_0.m3u8, media_1.m3u8, etc. , as described in the documentation.
Maybe I did not understand correctly how this should work?

Comment: You should use `-hls_playlist 1`.